# Website footer conflicting with <aside> content

Tags: css, html, joomla2.5

I have a site set up in Joomla [Here's the site](http://www.thebarnandpinncottage.co.uk/index.php) using a custom grid responsive template. At the moment I have a pretty basic layout... Header - Section - Aside - Footer.

The footer, however seems to rise up into the aside module and not sit below it like it does with the section component. I've tried every sticky footer solution but alas, I am defeated! Am I missing some pretty straight forward floats and clears here? Or is it that the footer is a module? Here's the code... the bits that should be relevant!

**index.php**

```
</head>

<body>

<?php  if($this->countModules('hidden')) : ?>
<div id="hidden">
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="hidden"  style="xhtml" />
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<header>
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="header" style="xhtml" />
</header>
<nav>
  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="nav" style="xhtml" />
</nav>

<section>
    <jdoc:include type="component" style="xhtml" />
</section> 


<?php  if($this->countModules('aside')) : ?>
<aside>
  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="aside" style="xhtml" />
</aside>
<?php endif; ?>

<footer>
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer"  style="xhtml" />
</footer>
```

**style.css**

```
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    font-family:'OpenSansRegular';
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
    overflow: hidden; /* Useful for mobile window width */
}


header {
    -webkit-background-size:    cover;
    -moz-background-size:       cover;
    -o-background-size:         cover;
    background-size:            cover;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #4B77B1;
}

section {
    background: white;
    color: #333;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-o-box-sizing:border-box;-ms-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;
}

aside {
    right: 0;
    color: #333;
}


footer {
    height: 200px;
    background: #B3BCC6;
    border-top: 4px solid #4B77B1;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

There is a responsive style sheet as well but the styles in the main css shown above override that. Hope someone can help!

I have added some background colours so it's easier to see the aside module misbehaving with the footer...

Comment: [link](http://www.thebarnandpinncottage.co.uk/contact) This page seems to have the problem as there is less content for example more stuff in the aside than the section.

Comment: Yes, I see. Your aside content have absolute positioning, and it's out of document flow. Why don't you use float properties to get this layout instead of absolute positioning?

Comment: Hi - I tried floating both the section and the aside and giving the footer a `clear: both;` but it seems nothing I do works. The aside always overlaps the footer...

Comment: @Miljan your note on the aside about it being absolutely positioned was correct, I didn't see it at first but it was my responsive style sheet that had it in. Playing around with this made other elements play correctly and with Jamie Patersons comments on adding widths it solved it!

Comment: Actually, my aside is now not maintaining it's position at the top of the page. I need to shift it over to the right and up to the top, however not using absolute positioning to maintain the responsive flow... I'm truly stuck and been staring at this for too long! Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html markup could do with jigging slightly. If you are using floated elements then all main containers should really be floated and some widths perhaps added to ensure IE7 plays ball. If you are not using floats then clear fixes should be used with / and / or css to content ::after{display:block; content:""; etc to clear elements down.

I would suggest more parent containers to encompass the left and right column then clear after that - that will push the footer down - think about adding widths though for some older browsers or include in a specific @import url.

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting. Are you suggesting then a wrapper around the section and aside then a clear for the footer? I think I did try this but maybe didn't implement it correctly...

Comment: Yep, anything I try seems to either break it, cause other issues or just not work... It's driving me crazy! I've tried floats, clear fixes... everything! I'm totally doing something wrong here.

Comment: Your comments along with Miljans help to solve the problem. I had absolute positioning on the aside and with you mentioning widths it solved the issue!

Comment: Actually, my aside is now not maintaining it's position at the top of the page. It is ok when the view port is narrower but not when it is full width... Any ideas?

Comment: I would strip out all absolute and rel positions and give widths and floats for starters then see what you have. Strip back / comment out media queries till one size works before adding back in.